# Chinese character doesn't support on ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, utf-8

actually I try to insert Chinese data to sqlite3 from ActionScript3 using CGI webservice script. for inserting English data it's working fine. But when I try to insert Chinese data, the URL goes like this                                  `/cgi-bin/reg.cgi?username=%E5%A5%A0%E5%9F%BA%E6%95%88%E6%9E%9C%E5%9B%BE`
and python script shows that `update Error`. I just googled and got a idea to use `encodeURIComponent("奠基效果图");` . When I use `encodeURIComponenet` it's insert data into my database as like this `%E5%A5%A0%E5%9F%BA%E6%95%88%E6%9E%9C%E5%9B%BE` . And also I tried `byteArray.writeUTF("奠基效果图");` , but when use `writeUTF()` my `URL` value goes `Null`. I think I need to use `encode UTF-8`. But I don't know how to use that on Action Script. kindly some one suggest some idea to solve this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that the server side script is saved as UTF-8 and is using `unicode()` to grab the data?

Comment: thanks for reply Maenu. actually for server side I am using python CGI script. do you have any idea about how to verify the Cgi script for UTF-8 ?

Comment: Hm, you should show the ActionScript that encodes the characters and the Python that decodes it.

Comment: I forgot to link to the [Python Unicode guide](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html), maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not think about the format which is stored in the Data Base, when you use the `encodeURIComponenet(str)` for encoding data, you just use `decodeURIComponent(rstr)` for retrieve from data base. it can retrieve the data with `decoded` fromat. I think this one helps.

Comment: yeah I have did the same way and works fine. but I think , this one is not the correct way to do this.